# Java SSL Input/Outputstream not working

Tags: java, io, java-io

Having an issue with my input/output streams. Connecting a client to a server via SSL, and trying to send a message from the client to server.

However, when I write to my outputstream, nothing is read on the other end.

*note* - I am running my buffer in a separate thread called sendReceive, so that it does not block the main application while waiting for input. I pass it an input of SSLSocket, and it then establishes the corresponding streams/buffers. I'm not sure if this is where the issue lies in itself.

Here's the relevant part of my server.

```
 static void initializeCLAConnection(){
        try {
            SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =
                    (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLServerSocket sslserversocket =
                    (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(3577);
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();

            System.out.println("Connection accepted from: "+sslserversocket.getInetAddress());


            //initialize buffer thread
            sendReceive CLABuf = new sendReceive(sslsocket);
            System.out.println("CLABuf established.");
            CLABuf.start();
```

When CLABuf.start() is called, it runs the following thread. Here, it never reaches the print statement "Receiving input", regardless of how many times I write to the stream.

```
    public class sendReceive extends Thread{
        InputStream inputstream;
        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader;
        BufferedReader bufferedreader;
        OutputStream outputstream;
        OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter;
        BufferedWriter bufferedwriter;

public sendReceive(SSLSocket socket) throws IOException{
     inputstream = socket.getInputStream();
     inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
     bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

     outputstream = socket.getOutputStream();
     outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream);
     bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(outputstreamwriter);

     System.out.println("CLA Buf established in new thread");
}
@Override
public void run() {
    //listen to inputstream
    String string=null;

    while(this.isAlive()){
         System.out.println("Buf running");

         try {
            while((string=this.bufferedreader.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println("Thread receiving input!");

             }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

and the relevant part of my client sending the msg.

```
public void initializeVoterToCLA(){
    try {
        /*
         * socket for Voter -> CLA
         */
       SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactoryCLA = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
       SSLSocket sslsocketCLA = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactoryCLA.createSocket("localhost", 3577);

       InputStream inputstreamVoter = sslsocketCLA.getInputStream();
       InputStreamReader inputstreamreaderVoter = new InputStreamReader(inputstreamVoter);
       BufferedReader bufferedreaderVoter = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreaderVoter);

       OutputStream outputstreamCLA = sslsocketCLA.getOutputStream();
       OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriterCLA = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstreamCLA);
       BufferedWriter bufferedwriterCLA = new BufferedWriter(outputstreamwriterCLA);

       //send msg
       bufferedwriterCLA.write("test msg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reading lines but you're not writing lines. Add a line terminator.

Nothing to do with SSL.

NB Testing `this.isAlive()` is futile. If it was false, the code that tests it wouldn't be running. This outer loop is completely pointless. Once the inner loop exits, there is nothing more to read. Just remove the outer loop.

Comment: Got rid of .isAlive() loop, also added line terminators to what I'm writing. Neither did anything, still doesn't receive anything

Comment: How would you know, when you never display any of it?

Comment: Because if it were reading a line it would get to the print statement